# Graph with text inside circles?

Tags: pdftex, tikz-styles, smartdiagram

All what I want is to get an image which give me eventually an image looks like this attached image (better if it is with some colors and high resolution level):
[image]

I understand fully that this is quite duplicated question, but as I tried some suggested solutions found here, I got always some errors and different shapes of wished image !

Please do not mention that this is a duplicated question and try at least help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with `pstricks`and `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, pdf, svgnames]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{ pst-node}
    \usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}

\sffamily
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}m{58mm}>{Apple:}lX@{}}
\smash{\raisebox{-\dimexpr\height + 3ex}{
\begin{pspicture}[]%
\LARGE
\cnodeput[framesep = 4pt]{0}(0,0){W}{\color{Goldenrod}WHY}
\pscircle(0,0){1.85}\rput(0,-1.3){HOW}
\pscircle(0,0){2.7}\rput(0,-2.25){WHAT}
\end{pspicture}}}
 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries\large}l}{WHY = The Purpose} \\
 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\itshape}l}{What is your cause? What do you believe?}\\[1ex]
 & & We believe in challenging the status quo and doing this differently \\[2ex]
 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\bfseries\large}l}{HOW = The Process} \\
 & \multicolumn{2}{>{\itshape}l}{Specific actions taken to realise the Why}\\[1ex]
 & & Our products are beautifully designed and easy to use \\[2ex]
 & \multicolumn{2}{ >{\bfseries\large}l}{WHAT = The Result} \\
 & \multicolumn{2}{ >{\itshape}l}{What do you do? The result of Why.Proof} \\[1ex]
 & & We make computers
\end{tabularx}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is really impressive work, but as I tried to run it in my TeX editor I got the following error: `Package auto-pst-pdf Error: . Or turn off auto-pst-pdf.}`

Comment: @AliMansour: How are you compiling?  `auto-pst-pdf`is for `pdflatex` with the switch `shell-escape` (under TeX Live or MacTex) or `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX). Removing `auto-pst-pdf`, you also can compile with `xelatex`, or use the traditional way `latex->dvips->pstopdf`