# How to draw circles inside each other in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw four circles inside each other, with some text in the area between the circles (naming that area).

So far I got:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}

\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(45:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\fourthcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw \firstcircle node[below] {$first$};
    \draw \secondcircle node [above] {$second$};
    \draw \thirdcircle node [below] {$third$};
    \draw \fourthcircle node [below] {$fourth$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

but I don't know what to do to:

1. make one circle bigger than each other (with fourth circle being the largest)
2. make the text not appear inside in the middle of the circle, but in the areas between the circles (it would be nice if the text arched following the circle)
3. make the circles appear inside each other.

Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There was an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405310/graph-with-text-inside-circles/405325#405325) to a very similar question at the beginning of this month (based on `pstricks`).

Answer (score 3):

Similar to marmot's answer, but using nodes for circles and decorating text added on top of them.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.text}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[circle, minimum size=8cm, draw, fill=red] (a) {};
\node[circle, minimum size=6cm, draw, fill=green] (b) {};
\node[circle, minimum size=4cm, draw, fill=blue] (c) {};
\node[circle, minimum size=2cm, draw, fill=orange] (d) {O};

\draw [decorate, decoration={text along path, text = Some text for first circle}] (180:3.5) arc (180:0:3.5cm); 

\draw [decorate, decoration={text along path, text = Some text for second circle}] (150:2.5) arc (150:60:2.5cm); 

\draw [decorate, decoration={text along path, text = Some text for third circle}] (90:1.5) arc (90:-90:1.5cm); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I really did not fully understand what you want. This post is an attempt to clarify this. Here is a snippet that produces concentric circles with increasing radii and some annotations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text} % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268612/how-to-write-a-text-along-a-circle


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue,postaction={decorate},decoration={text along path,
text={first},text align=center}]
(6,0) arc [start angle=0,end angle=360,radius=1];
\draw[blue,postaction={decorate},decoration={text along path,
text={second},text align=center}]
(5,-2) arc [start angle=-90,end angle=270,radius=2];
\draw[blue,postaction={decorate},decoration={text along path,
text={third},text align=center}]
(2,0) arc [start angle=-180,end angle=180,radius=3];
\draw[blue,postaction={decorate},decoration={text along path,
text={fourth},text align=center}]
(5,4) arc [start angle=-270,end angle=90,radius=4];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If this is not what you want, I'll be happy to remove this post.